# Prerender dynamic routes on Lambda and save on s3

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, angular-universal

I have enabled angular universal in my application and am able to do [prerendering](https://angular.io/guide/prerendering) for some static routes (like home page, about, etc).

Now I also need to prerender some extra routes, but I need to be able to do this whenever it is needed, after the website has already been deployed. A live use-case would be if Airbnb wanted to prerender the new ads when people posted them.

I was thinking to have a Lambda function that I could trigger (when the ad is added for this example) that would run prerendering, then save the `index.html` file on the s3 bucket (I have CloudFront already on top of that).

But how to actually generate the files on Lambda? I am currently doing it at build time using:

```
ng run my-app:prerender
```

Note: I do not want to serve the files from the lambda, I want to generate them (prerender) and save on s3

Comment: can you share some more details about the answer? If possible a github url to see the code?

Comment: @aneeshere you mean the code in the answer below? maybe you could add your comment on the answer directly? and what more details would you need? I don't have this code in a public repo atm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make it work by reading the source code of the universal prerendering package, and here is what works:

```js
const { resolve, join } = require('path');
const { setup, render } = require('@nguniversal/builders/src/prerender/worker.js');

const [ route ] = process.argv.slice(2);

const ROOT = resolve(__dirname);
const outputPath = join(ROOT, 'dist', 'browser');
const serverBundlePath = join(ROOT, 'dist', 'server', 'main.js');

setup({
  indexFile: 'index.html',
  deployUrl: '',
  inlineCriticalCss: true,
  minifyCss: true
});

render(outputPath, serverBundlePath, route).then(() => {
  console.log('Build', route, 'done');
  process.exit(0);
}).catch(err => {
  console.error(err);
  process.exit(1);
});
```

After running once `npm run prerender` (like explained in the Angular tutorials), I can now prerender any route by just doing `node prerender.js /my-route`